# How to select multiple options with mat-radio-group

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am using mat-radio-group to have multiple radio buttons but I am unable to select/check multiple radio buttons (radio buttons are generated by iterating through an array). I have also tried coding it so that the radio buttons all have the same name but I am still unable to select multiple values.

```
    <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="question.answered" fxFlex>
      <mat-radio-button [disabled]="result" name="test" class="example-radio-button" [value]="answer"
        *ngFor="let answers of question.getanswers">
        {{answers}}
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
```

What is it I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons are not supposed to be multi-selectable. You want some checkboxes instead.

Comment: Thanks @user2793505 still working my way round angular

Answer (score 0):

You add an attribute on your mat-radio-button only change the name for only item
[name]="i"

Comment: Welcome to SO. This answer does not contain enough detail/clarity. Please either repost as comment or expand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar problem, this result worked for me, i stored the option in the array used the position of my "question", my object has an attribute called position, so i use to set the [(ngModel)]="testAnswerDtoList[question . position]" storing the value in an array, then in the value of the radiobutton, I pass a structured object with the values ​​I need {position, value}.

```
<div *ngFor="let question of recurso.testQuestions" style="padding-left: 5%">
        <b>{{ question.position }}. {{ question.description }}</b>
        <mat-radio-group  *ngFor="let itemQuestion of question.itemQuestions"
        [(ngModel)]="testAnswerDtoList[question.position]"
        >
            <div style="padding-left: 5%">
                <mat-radio-button [value]="{
                    'testQuestionId': question.id,
                    'value':itemQuestion.position
                }">
                    {{ itemQuestion.position }} {{ itemQuestion.description }}
                </mat-radio-button>
            </div>
        </mat-radio-group>
        <br />
    </div>
```

TS:

testAnswerDtoList: TestAnswerDto[] = [];

I hope I have explained well the solution that worked for me.